# STM32F429-DISC1 LCD prints double pixels

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to print pixels on the LCD of `STM32F429-DISC1` by directly writing to the SDRAM in an ARGB4444 configuration.

On the `stm32f429i_discovery_lcd.c` file I have changed the following line:

```
LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_PixelFormat = LTDC_Pixelformat_RGB565
```

for

```
LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_PixelFormat = LTDC_Pixelformat_ARGB4444;
```

In my main I call the following initializers:

```
LCD_Init();
LCD_LayerInit();
LTDC_Cmd(ENABLE);
```

and finally I try to print `red the 60500th pixel on Layer 1`. I multiply by 2 because addresses are 32 bits.

```
*(uint32_t *) (SDRAM_BANK_ADDR + 60500 * 2) = 0xFF00;
```

As a side note:

```
uint32_t SDRAM_BANK_ADDR = 0xD0000000 //Beginning of Layer 1
```

The red pixel gets printed, but besides there's a black pixel.
Here is a picture:
[image: Correct Red Pixel + Incorrect Pixel]

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In what format are pixels stored?

Comment: @Lundin  ARGB4444

Comment: That's not a format. Is this a DMA buffer? If so how is each pixel stored? How many bytes/bits per pixel, what's the color resolution and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_PixelFormat = LTDC_Pixelformat_ARGB4444;
```

seems to imply that pixels are 16-bit. Since this is on a microcontroller, I would assume the framebuffer to be packed, i.e. 16 bits per pixel.

But this:

```
*(uint32_t *) (SDRAM_BANK_ADDR + 60500 * 2) = 0xFF00;
```

writes 32 bits, i.e. it clobbers the neighboring pixel too. Note that the above does not cast the actual address when calculating it, that is done by inside the right set of parenthesis. The exact type at which the calculation is made depends on the type of `SDRAM_BANK_ADDR`, which is `uint32_t`. That integer value then needs to be cast into a pointer to the pixel, before the write, and that is done by the cast to the left.

A fix would simply be:

```
*(uint16_t *) (SDRAM_BANK_ADDR + 60500 * 2) = 0xFF00;
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue! I used uint32_t because the adresses are 32 bits, but pixels are 16 bits. Could you please elaborate on why this is the case?